# Django-postgress: Partial Index on timestamp

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Consider

```
queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(enabled=False) | Q(expires_at__isnull=False) & Q(expires_at__lte=timezone.now()) |
            )
```

I would like to have a partial index to support this query. AFAIK, this index will not be used during the execution of the above query because the value of `timezone.now()` changes. On the other hand, if I just index `enabled` that is also not useful because the query planner has to go through the second condition anyway.
What can be the best way to optimize this?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: A lot of people who otherwise might be able to help you out will have no idea what SQL Django turns that thing into.

Comment: I just thought adding SQL would look a bit messy :p

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one better way to do it.
Partial indexing '`expired_at`' for the condition
`enabled=False and expires_at is not null`.

Query planner doesn't have to scan the entire table in this case.